# wait until completing WMIC process call create cmd.exe to run bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

I'm running a bat file located on a remote server.
The command is: wmic /node:[server name] process call create  "cmd.exe /c [bat file location].
I would like the command to wait until the batch file execution completing. In other words: the command is part of Jenkins (Hudson) job, and the next step after the window batch command starting before the batch file tasks completed. I would like the next step to be executed just after the batch file execution completing. * The batch file task (content) is restoring of a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Next *commented* code snippet could do the job. Unfortunately, I can test it only on local node.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_toRun=cmd.exe /C pause"   change to meet your circumstances 
set "_where=."                  sorry testing merely local computer 

set "_toGet=ProcessId ReturnValue"
set "_ProcessId="
set "_ReturnValue="
    rem %%G loop to get raw return values from `create` like next two lines
    rem ProcessId = 6476;
    rem ReturnValue = 0;
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('
  wmic /node:"%_where%" process call create "%_toRun%" ^| findstr "%_toGet%"
') do (
        rem %%g loop to assign values to variables `_ProcessId` and `_ReturnValue`
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;= " %%g in ("%%~G") do ( 
      set "_%%~g=%%~h"
    )
)
if NOT "%_ReturnValue%"=="0" (
  echo %_toRun% failed, Return Value %_ReturnValue%
  goto :notest 
)
echo process %_toRun% runs as %_ProcessId%

    rem build WQL query
set "_query=ProcessId = %_ProcessId% and CommandLine = '%_toRun:\=\\%'"

    rem loop while queried process runs 
:test
set "_CommandLine="
for /F %%G in ('
  wmic /node:"%_where%" process where "%_query%" get CommandLine /value ^| findstr "="
') do set "_%%~G"
if not defined _CommandLine goto :notest
set _Comman
>NUL timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK 
goto :test

:notest
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>NUL`, `|` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`%_toRun:\=\\%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)
- (`%%`, `""`, `^` etc. special page)  [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)